# qt5 qml c++ interaction

Tags: c++, qt

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#connecting-to-qml-signals

I've read most of that article, and seem to understand everything except for the part in c++. `QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                     &myClass, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));`

It is clear where `item`, `SIGNAL`, `myClass`, `SLOT`, `cppSlot` and `QString` come from, but where does `qmlSignal` come from? Of course it comes from the .qml file, but then how does the compiler find out about it if it's loaded via runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is clear where item, SIGNAL, myClass, SLOT, cppSlot and QString
>   come from, but where does qmlSignal come from? Of course it comes from
>   the .qml file, but then how does the compiler find out about it if
>   it's loaded via runtime?

qmlSignal is emitted by QML code and caught on C++ side as you noted. And compiler knows nothing of what is happening at run time except C++ types the code deals with.

The root QML item is reflected to QObject that has a nested list of signals and slots very much like pure C++ QObject. Every signal and slot has a test string signature and slots also have the mapping to certain class member.

```
QQuickView view(QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));
QObject *item = view.rootObject(); // get QObject from QML root

MyClass myClass;
QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)), // find "qmlSignal(QString)" in the list of signals of 'item'
                 &myClass, SLOT(cppSlot(QString))); // connect that signal entry to the found cppSlot(QString) entry of myClass object
```

For better understanding of signal-slot internals there is a good article: http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html

The above is of course is about string-based connections: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html

Not so many articles on QML signal/slot bindings but some: http://www.kdab.com/qml-engine-internals-part-2-bindings/

Comment: Is it safe to assume the MOC does a lot of the heavy lifting to get it to compile? I would imagine so based on the comments that you made to annotate the code.

Comment: Yes, MOC does lift stuff for us. We use it, no problems.